# Apache / Symfony2: Redirect everything besides few routes and / to another host

Tags: php, symfony, mod-rewrite, apache2

Hosting a Symfony2 application on Apache2.4 (fpm on prod, mod_php on devel).

On a subdomain (.xxx) we want to redirect everything *besides* the URIs `/` and `/sp(.*)` to our main domain (.com). Unfortunately there's no way to negate the matching expression in a `RedirectMatch` which would make this possible:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName  www.lsk.xxx
   RedirectMatch 301 !^(/$)|(/sp(.*))$ http://www.lsk.com/$1
   # ! is not possible here.
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.lsk.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I found one expression that would allow me to redirect `/sp` pages only but that doesn't take the root `/` into account. (That one is my favourite but how to write a regex that also takes `/` into account??):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/((?!sp).*)$ http://www.lsk.com/$1
```

Next we went `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sp
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.lsk.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

so `/` and `/sp` would force a passthru and everything else would be redirected to another host. That isn't working, though: the last line is still evaluated on `/` and `/sp` ! After watching the rewrite log this seems due to our Symfony2  framework's rewrite rules (front page controller) that force the rewrite engine to start another rewrite cycle containing an `app[_dev].php` (not matching the two rules and therefore being forwarded).

We have already "solved" this issue by appending a condition that matches the framework specific request uri (see my next answer) but I find that fix not very clever since it introduces application knowledge into my infrastructure. Anyone knows a better way around it?

Answer (score 0):

A rather "dirty" fix is this one, taking Symfony2's 2nd rewrite cycle into account:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sp [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/app # yuck
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [PT,L]

RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.lsk.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```